# How to implement a parameter variation that modifies a "JPA entitiy-object structure"?

Tags: jpa, entity, batch-processing

**Short version:**

I want to load an object tree from a database and then modify it in memory (by applying a settings file) to be able to perform parameter variations. Are there best practices for doing so? Does JPA give me some support for this, e.g. to update the persistence context from an additional "diff-database"? Are there parameter variation/sweep/batch frameworks supporting JPA persistence out there?

**Long version:**

I have a simulation program 'Simulator' that loads its business objects from a MySQL database using JPA (Hibernate): you can imagine a tree structure of objects that is loaded from the database. The classes of the business objects correspond to tables (foo, bar, qux) in the database.

Object Tree:

```
foo_root (id =1)
+ bar_first (id =1)
 ++ qux_large (id = 1)
+ bar_second (id = 2)
 ++ qux_small (id = 2)
 ++ qux_medium (id = 3)
 ++ qux_huge (id = 4)
```

An object in the tree (e.g. 'bar_first' ) corresponds to a row in a database table and has a unique id in that table. The attribute values of the objects correspond to entries in the columns of that table. For example the table 'qux' contains a column 'color' and the object 'qux_large' (id 1 in table qux) has the attribute color = green.

The simulation program works well for a single simulation. Now I want to implement a second program 'SweepMaster' that is able to perform a parameter variation / sweep / batch:

- A user specifies some parameters to be modified and ranges of values for those parameters. A parameter might correspond to a complete object (-id) or to an attribute of an object in the object tree.

  - The SweepMaster creates a set of input files and calls the Simulator for each individual input file.
  - The Simulator loads the object tree using JPA and modifies the tree (some objects/attributes) by applying the data from a single input file. Then it performs the simulation.
  - After the Simulator is finished the SweepMaster will start the next simulation with the next input file.

One individual input file specifies for example to

- load the object tree that starts with 'foo_root' (id = 1)
- use a color=yellow for 'qux_large'
- replace the complete object 'bar_second' with an object 'bar_third' (id = 3)

Another input file might specify to

- use another object tree, starting with 'foo_alternative_root' (id = 2)
- use a memory_size=500 for 'foo_alternative_root'

How should I implement that modification of the object tree?

**Options:**

Following options came to my mind:

**I.** The Simualator loads an object tree from the database and than **modifies the object tree in memory**.

**a)** The input file is passed through the object tree and each object in the tree checks if it should be modified and if so it changes its attributes or exchanges some child objects. In order to be able to exchange a child object it will have to be able to load the new child object from the database. (Or such new child objects would have have to be determined at the beginning and passed through the tree together with the input file.)

**b)** A settings controller changes the attributes of the whole tree, e.g. by reflection. It does not need to walk through the whole tree. It just handles some specific tree locations that are given in the input file.

**II.** The Simulator loads the complete database and copies it to an **in-memory-database**. It applies the input file by adapting the in-memory-database with SQL queries. In a third step it uses JPA to load the object tree from the modified in-memory-database.

**III.** The SweepMaster creates **many temporary duplicates** of the object tree in the **original database** and modifies them according to the user input. Then it instructs the Simulator to use those adapted duplicates. After the parameter variation is finished the SweepMaster deletes the temporary files.

Are there further solutions? What are your experiences with similar tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for option I b) and I will introduce some custom annotations for the fields that can be used in the parameter variation, e.g

- @ParameterPath("foo_root")
- @Parameter("qux_huge")

foo.baa = 5

This will give me the option to do internal refactoring (e.g. change the name of a field) without the direct need to change the input file for the parameter variation.

The settings controller will walk through the input file and search the corresponding annotated fields by reflection. It will also ask a Factory to create the object that should be used as value for that field. Finally the settings controller will set the value of the field by reflection.

If I want to use an additional field with a new type for my parameter variations, I will have to annotate that field and extend the factory for the new type.